# Data not inside HTML table, Laravel PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, html-table

I just started using Laravel and wanted some data from my database to be in a html table, but not the php loads outside the table.

This is my code, This is done in Laravel.

```
<table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>id</th>
                                    <th>merk</th>
                                    <th>type</th>
                                    <th>color</th>
                                    <th>price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php
                                use App\Models\Shoe;
                                foreach (Shoe::all() as $shoe) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <tb> <?php echo $shoe->id ?> </tb>
                                        <tb> <?php echo $shoe->merk ?> </tb>
                                        <tb> <?php echo $shoe->type ?> </tb>
                                        <tb> <?php echo $shoe->color ?> </tb>
                                        <tb> <?php echo $shoe->price ?> </tb>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

So all the php stuff loads and then comes the , idk how to make it that the database information actually shows inside the table

I'm probably just really dumb here but I've tried multible ways but I always keep getting this result. Anyone who can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the source of the HTML page? How does it look like

Comment: And do `<td>` not `<tb>`

Comment: Thanks IT goldman, Changing TB to TD fixed it.

I feel pretty dumb RN haha, wasted a full hour trying everything but i just typed it wrong.
Anyways thanks again